# Paypal Subscription Button Upgrade Membership

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-buttons

I created 2 Subscribe button with paypal. This buttons for different membership : 1. basic 2. pro.
I am trying to subscribe membership with thisbuttons and working without any problem.
But when I was trying to upgrade or downgrade via other buttons paypal create new membership. So If I use 2 buttons for membership I have 2 active membership: pro and basic on paypal. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "modify" variable in the subscription button, so that the existing subscription will get modify and there will be only one subscription. Click [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_subscribe/#modify-subscription-button) for more information.

Comment: The link you provided is broken. The page is showing a 404 status code error. Can you provide more detail (coding) as to how to implement the revise paypal subscription plan using the smart buttons